Increase and decrease brightness keys take long to work
I have recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS alongside with Windows 11 (previously installed and working properly) and whenever I press the f6 and f7 keys (in my PC, they're responsable for decreasing and increasing screen brightness), the screen takes a long to time do change it's brightness and my OS gets very slow for some seconds. My pc is a DELL G15 5525

Takes a long time do you mean seconds, minutes or hours please edit and add some meaningful info.
